# How to only allow specific Input in C

Tags: c

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char checkInput0(void);

int main() {
   char output;
   output = checkInput0();
   printf("The output is %c", output);
}

char checkInput0(void){
    char option0 = '\0',check0;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Please enter your choice: ");

         if(scanf("%c %c",option0, &c) != 'A' || c != 'B' ){
            while((check0 = getchar()) != 0 && check0 != '\n' && check0 != EOF);
            printf("[ERR] Please enter A or B.\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    return option0;
}
```

I would like to only allow the user to input only "A" or "B" and if anything else would be entered I would like to reprompt the user with the following message: [ERR] Please enter A or B.\n

I have written a funktion which worked with numbers but I can't get the one above (checkInput0) to work, what have I done wrong

Answer (score 2):

1. `scanf` does not *return* `c`, it returns the number of variables successfully set. Comparing that to `'A'` is pretty pointless.
2. Change your `scanf` call to `scanf("%c %c", &option0, &c)`: currently the behaviour is undefined: the variable arguments need to be pointer types.
3. `x != 'A' || x != 'B'` is `1` for any value of `x`.

Consider moving `scanf` outside the `if` conditional: checking the return value of `scanf` explicitly. On the third point, did you want `&&`?

Also be careful with *ace* code that writes `c` on one side of an operator, and reads it on the other. It's fine in this instance since `||` is a sequencing point, but you are quite close to undefined behaviour here.

Comment: ok I changed `||` to `&&` but I get the following error message "1.c:17:22: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'int' [-Wformat]
    if(scanf("%c %c",option0, &c) != 'A' && c != 'B' ){
              ~~     ^~~~~~~
"

Comment: @HiChaps: You need to move the `scanf` outside the `if` block (unless you write some fancy expression).

Comment: Also note that `scanf("%c %c",option0, &c)` will invoke UB.

Comment: @babon: Pinched that. Ta.

Comment: Having moved the scanf out of the if block, I always get a segmentation fault